# Spinning objects in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

How do I make an object, for example an image, rotate forever?

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: ({

    self.Cube.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(320)

}))
```

Does anyone have a solution, would really appreciate some help.

Comment: you can use NSTimer ?

Comment: thanks!, but do you mean that it trigs the image to rotate every time the timer ends. So it repeats every time? If you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function to rotate a layer forever.

```
func rotateLayer(layer:CALayer,duration:CFTimeInterval){
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation");
    animation.fromValue = 0;
    animation.duration = duration;
    animation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI*2);
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear);
    animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity;

    layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "rotation");
}
```

usage (the duration is time it takes the layer to rotate 360 degress):

```
rotateLayer(subView.layer, duration: 2);
```

Comment: Thanks!, I am kind of new to this so to where do a call this function?

Comment: You could call it in viewDidLoad for example or in any other function

Comment: Thank you so much:), really appreciate it .